# Processing very large files in R

Tags: r, out-of-memory, parquet

I have a dataset that is 188 million rows with 41 columns. It comes as a massive compressed fixed width file and I am currently reading it into R using the `vroom` package like this:

```
d <- vroom_fwf('data.dat.gz', 
          fwf_positions([41 column position], 
                        [41 column names])
```

`vroom` does a wonderful job here in the sense that the data are actually read into an R session on a machine with 64Gb of memory. When I run `object.size` on `d` it is a whopping 61Gb is size. When I turn around to do anything with this data I can't. All I get back the `Error: cannot allocate vector of size {x} Gb` because there really isn't any memory left to much of anything with that data. I have tried base R with `[`, `dplyr::filter` and trying to convert to a data.table via `data.table::setDT` each with the same result.

So my question is what are people's strategies for this type of thing? My main goal is to convert the compressed fixed width file to a parquet format but I would like to split it into small more manageable files based on some values in a column in the data then write them to parquet (using `arrow::write_parquet`)

My ideas at this point are to read a subset of columns keeping the column that I want to subset by, write the parquet files then bind the columns/merge the two back together. This seems like a more error prone solution though so I thought I would turn here and see what is available for further conversions.

Comment: You might want to look into the [disk.frame](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame) package

Comment: I would use a stream command line tool like sed or awk for the initial splitting. Afterwards, you can read the chunks into `R`. For example: `awk -F ',' '{print > ("data"_$1".txt")}' test.txt` reads the file `test.txt`, splits by commas and partitions into files `data_*.txt` based on the first column's contents. See http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-split-file-into.html for example.